# Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ListenableFuture<String>

Tags: spring

I'm trying to implementing non-blocking call. in spring 4, But unfortunately it's throwing the below error.

Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ListenableFuture

and also same error can not able convert from  Map to ListenableFuture>.

My Method call stack is as below.

```
ListenableFuture<Map<String,String>> unusedQuota = doLogin(userIdentity,request,"0");
```

doLogin login simply return Map

is there any converter required?

what changes would be required ?

Thanks.

```
public class MyController {



final DeferredResult<Map<String,String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<Map<String,String>>(5000l);

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

 @Inject
 RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginservice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Timed
    public DeferredResult<Map<String,String>> loginRequestService(@RequestParam String userIdentity,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        deferredResult.onTimeout(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { // Retry on timeout
                deferredResult.setErrorResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT).body("Request timeout occurred."));
            }
        });

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ListenableFuture<Map<String,String>> unusedQuota =  doLogin(userIdentity,request);
        unusedQuota.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Map<String,String>>() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Map<String, String> result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                deferredResult.setResult((Map<String, String>) ResponseEntity.ok(result));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                deferredResult.setErrorResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(t));
            }

        });             
        return deferredResult;

    }


    private Map<String,String> doLogin(String userIdentity,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{

        Map<String,String> unusedQuota=new HashMap<String,String>();

        unusedQuota.put("quota", "100");
        return unusedQuota;
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: Is this inside a controller ? Post us the whole method code

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT passing the `Map` object when there is an exception which is causing the issue, so your controller method needs to be changed as shown below, also move `deferredResult` object inside the Controller method as you should share the same instance of `deferredResult` for different user request.

```
public class MyController {

     @Autowired
     private TaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor; 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginservice", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Timed
    public DeferredResult<Map<String,String>> loginRequestService(@RequestParam String userIdentity,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

                final DeferredResult<Map<String,String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<Map<String,String>>(5000l);

                deferredResult.onTimeout(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() { // Retry on timeout
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        //Populate map object with error details with Request timeout occurred.

                        deferredResult.setErrorResult(new ResponseEntity
                                   <Map<String, String>>(map, null,  
                                          HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT));

                    }
                });

            ListenableFuture<String> task = asyncTaskExecutor.submitListenable(new Callable<String>(){
        @Override
        public Map<String,String> call() throws Exception {
            return doLogin(userIdentity,request);
        }
        });

                unusedQuota.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Map<String,String>>() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Map<String, String> result) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        deferredResult.setResult((Map<String, String>) ResponseEntity.ok(result));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        //Populate map object with error details

                       deferredResult.setErrorResult(new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(
                       map, null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
                    }

                });       
                return deferredResult;
            }
     }
```

Also, you need to ensure that you are configuring the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as explained in the example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/).

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ListenableFuture<Map<String,String>> unusedQuota =   doLogin(userIdentity,request);  at this location i'm getting same error. I did the changes what you have suggested but no luck.

Comment: Also, your doLogin() should be running in callable to return `ListenableFuture`, updated the answer, check it

Comment: Thanks for update. But i have done by using AsyncRestTemplate.